# Hover links not covering the entire height of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, navbar

My hover links have a background color but they're not covering up the whole height of the navbar. Please help. I've tried inline-block and 100% height, it didn't work.

UPDATE- I did get this solved with the suggestion provided by @PizzaBoy below, but now I'm stuck with the .active background looking the same as it did before with a weird half-border / background around each link. Any suggestions to make the .active link to look like the hover would be wonderful. Thank you ahead.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
.background-wrap {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1000;
}
#video-bg-elem {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
.navbar{
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
}
#brand-image{
    height: 100px;
}
a.navbar-brand{
    position: relative;
}

.navbar{
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
}
.navbar-nav > li{
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2vh;
    font-size: 2.3vw;
    font-family: 'Freestyle Script';
    font-weight: 900;
 color: rgb(210, 21, 84) !important;
    padding-bottom: 0.2%;
}
.navbar-nav > li:hover,
.navbar-nav > li:focus {
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
    transition: .5s;
}
.navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">

    <title>Arks Digital Marketing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Video Background -->
    <div class="background-wrap">
  
        <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay loop="loop" muted="muted">
                    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Video not supported
                    </video>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="mynav">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
              <img id="brand-image" alt="Brand" src="logo.png"</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blogs </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

add this css

```
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
margin: -7px;
}
```

change you existing code into

```
.navbar-nav > li {
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 33px 5px;
}
```

Comment: @PizzaBoy- You're so amazing! It's perfect!

Comment: @PizzaBoy- That did justice to my hover. But how do I make the .active look the same as the hover? The .active has that weird half-complete border around the active pages... Thank you for your help!

Comment: If it's solved your question, make sure to upvote and mark as the accepted answer. Also, please review my edit to your question to make sure I didn't make a mistake, it seemed like the code in the codepen and question didn't match. So I've converted it to a stack snippet instead of a codepen, to reduce reliance on external sites.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, I'm still new, that's why I can't vote it up, but thank you loads, for converting the codes for me. I still have an additional question (see UPDATE), if you can solve that, that would be soo cool!!

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this code.**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}
.background-wrap {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1000;
}
#video-bg-elem {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
.navbar{
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
}
#brand-image{
    height: 100px;
}
a.navbar-brand{
    position: relative;
}

.navbar{
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
}
.navbar-nav > li{
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2vh;
    font-size: 2.3vw;
    font-family: 'Freestyle Script';
    font-weight: 900;
   color: rgb(210, 21, 84) !important;
    padding-bottom: 0.2%;
   display: block;
}
.navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
    display: block;
}
.navbar-nav > li a:hover,
.navbar-nav > li a:focus {
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.4) !important;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
    <!-- Video Background -->
    <div class="background-wrap">
  
        <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted="muted">
                    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Video not supported
                    </video>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="mynav">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
              <img id="brand-image" alt="Brand" src="logo.png"</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blogs </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
    </div>
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Dhaval, I tried this code today, unfortunately it started to hover the half border around the background instead of fixing the full border background I already have in the active pages. Thank you for helping me :)